# why qt can run without x server and gtk cant

Tags: qt, gtk, x11, gstreamer

I am developing a gstreamer based app on AM335x starter kit running arago linux. "gst-launch"(with a test pipeline) gives proper command line output (serial) but  shows nothing on the screen. BTW the screen by default shows a qt demo app. Killing this demo app makes the gst-launch fail.

I compiled a "hello world" gtk app, which gives "Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:" error. BTW there is no X here.

But when I ran  a Qt "hello world" app, a pop up window was displayed on top of the demo app.

Can someone please explain why. Any suggestions to solve this are welcome.

UPDATE1:
Correct me if I am wrong. I was thinking maybe using qt-gstreamer API might be the easiest way.

UPDATE2:
I am able to make this work using the "fbdevsink"  gstreamer plugin.
Thanks to all for the pointers.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds very weird.

GTK+ relies on GDK for its drawing and input needs, and GDK uses different *backends* for different platforms and environments.

The X11 backend is one, but there are others.

You simply must make sure you build GDK with a suitable backend for your environment.

Answer (score 2):

GTK+ requires a working windowing system — i.e. X11, Windows, MacOS X, or Wayland — in order to display content and handle events.

Older versions of GTK+ allowed using the Linux frame buffer device, or DirectFB, as the windowing system, but both backends have been deprecated and are either removed in newer versions of the GTK+ library, or unmaintained and likely broken.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not experienced with GTK, but my understanding is, that GTK itself is very much a graphics toolkit. It is the very part, which requires a graphics backend to work. There are other stuff which does not require that, and they are put in GLib.

Qt is much more general purpose toolkit, it has a lot of features built in, for which you'd use some other library if you had a GTK GUI. With Qt you can build application which does not require graphics backend, *but you have to create the application object instance from `QCoreApplication` class*. If you have a Qt application which uses `QApplication`, and you try to run it without having graphics backend, you get error too.

Reason is practicality and keeping things simple, and perhaps also just having a suboptimal design, which makes separting some things from graphics backend difficult. A lot of things really depend on having the graphics backend, and adding special cases for situations where there isn't one can be seen as extra complexity (==work and bugs) for little benefit.

---

As to 2nd part of your question, I don't know a workaround for GTK, other than, don't use it if you don't actually mean to draw anything. But I think generally, you would need to provide a "dummy" graphics backend, which can satisfy the requirements without actually having a screen.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least the following ways to achive a non-X supplied gtk capplication:

- GTK Framebuffer (gtkfb)

You can find further information about it: http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/gtk/gtk-framebuffer.html

- Do not use graphics functionality at all

This is a bit more drastic, so you would need to stick to things like glib, et cetera.